# Android android:background auto rotate option

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I set a background image to a layout via the android:background property. I want the image to rotate when displayed in a landscape orientation. Right now it keeps its same orientation and gets stretched badly.

To fix I rotated the image myself in Photoshop and put one copy in drawable-port and one in drawable-land. While this does fix the issue, it causes me to grow the app size by a few megs to fit alternate versions of all the images. Is there anyway to do this via the xml without the need for extra copies of the images?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test it, bu I would use the `android:rotation` attribute in the drawable-land to rotate the same image resource 90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried looking for a android:rotation attribute but I do not think that it exists.

Comment: Oh now I see it. Its for API level 11 and I am on 8 thats why I could not see it.

Comment: OK, same idea, API 1: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html